# Bootcamp won't start after resizing partition

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp

My system is divided in two and shared using Boot Camp feature. Recently I needed more space on the Mac partition and whiled loaded only in the Windows partition, I have shrank my Windows partition by 10 Gb using Windows disk management tool.

Now I can no longer start up the Boot Camp bridge while in the Mac OS X side to access the Windows partition. I suspect the Boot Camp file no longer recognize this modified Windows partition.

Is there a quick to solve this issue without having to reinstall everything?

Comment: I suppose if the gpt now differs from the MBR table you may not be able to boot back to Windows. If your Mac is new enough to boot from the internet then you could just enter the gpt command from a terminal to correct the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This error occurred because in a Boot Camp setup, your hard drive has a hybrid GPT/MBR partition table, which is unsupported by Microsoft.  When you resized the partition in Windows, it only modified the MBR partition table because it was unaware that the GPT table existed.  You now have a situation where the GPT partition table and the MBR partition table disagree about the start/end boundaries of the Windows partition.

To fix this, you will need to use the `gpt` command line tool, and for that you must boot from OS X install media (either a USB flash drive, or Internet Recovery if your model supports that feature -- the recovery partition will not work for this).

1. Boot from OS X install media and open up a command prompt.
2. Type `fdisk /dev/disk0` to see the MBR partition table. Write down
   the partition number (it's usually 4), the start sector, and the
   size of the Windows partition. The start sector and size will be big
   numbers so make sure you write them down correctly.  This is
   critical.
3. Type `diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk0`  This will unmount the disk
   so GPT can write to it.
4. Type `gpt remove -i 4 /dev/disk0` **NOTE** that the '4' here
   references the partition number of your Windows partition you got
   from `fdisk` earlier.  This will delete the GPT partition entry for
   your Windows partition (but not the MBR entry)
5. Type `fdisk -d /dev/disk0 >/Volumes/fdisk.txt`  This will  make a
   backup of the MBR partition table.
6. Type `fdisk -e /dev/disk0`  This will put the `fdisk` command in
   interactive edit mode. You will need to enter the following input.
   **NOTE** that the '4' here references the partition number of your Windows partition you got from `fdisk` earlier.  This will delete
   the MBR partition entry for your Windows partition.

   ```
   e 4
   0
   q
   y
   ```
7. Type `diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk0` again because the `gpt`
   command caused OS X to remount the disk and we need to modify it
   again.
8. Type `gpt add -b <start sector> -s <size> -i 4 -t windows
   /dev/disk0` where 'start sector', 'size', and '4' are the values you
   wrote down from the `fdisk` command earlier.
9. For good measure, type `gpt show /dev/disk0` to view the GPT table. 
   Make sure the partition number, start sector, and size match the
   `fdisk` output from step 2 EXACTLY.
10. Type `diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk0` again because the `gpt`
     command caused OS X to remount the disk and we need to modify it
     again.
11. Type `fdisk -r -y /dev/disk0 </Volumes/fdisk.txt` This will undo
     the changes made in step 6.
12. For good measure, type `fdisk /dev/disk0` to view the MBR table. Make sure the output matches the `fdisk` output from step 2 EXACTLY.

You have now repaired your GPT table.  You should be able to reboot the Mac into either operating system now.

Comment: Thank you for editing that for me, @DavidAnderson. You took some work off my shoulders!

Comment: hi, in this part it returns me error :" Type diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk0 This will unmount the disk so GPT can write to it." unmount failed for dev/disk0 nad i use force command but its not working too . please help me i have same problem. :(

Comment: You must be booted from external media for this command to work. Either from a USB stick or Internet Recovery (i.e. Cmd+Opt+R).  Booting to the recovery environment (Cmd+R) is not sufficient, as you will be booted from a partition of the disk you're trying to modify. You can't unmount the disk in that scenario.

Comment: how i can boot from external USB? i try to boot from internet but i faced that problem again. @wesSayeed

Comment: This is really bad advice and will break your mac, you can lose the entire disk if ANYTHING goes wrong, I strongly advise you to not follow these steps.