# After resizing partition in MacOS, Bootcamp doesn't boot. having tried to fix, modified MBR (or GPT), MacOS doesn't even see Bootcamp partition

Tags: bootcamp, partition

First, here is the situation;
To increase bootcamp partition (Windows 10), I diminished macOS partition size from MacOS from Disk Utility app (by the pie chart). Then Windows did not boot. There were many articles about this problem and I learned that it was because Windows partition number in MBR became greater than what it can boot. to fix it, I followed instruction here (only later though, I realized the instruction was not meant for my situation - he resized by Windows application while I did by Mac);
[Bootcamp won't start after resizing partition](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/180352/bootcamp-wont-start-after-resizing-partition)
although without really understanding, I carefully followed the instruction and typed all commands correctly. but it still does not boot. moreover, when I see Disk Utility in macOS again, I no longer see the Windows partition which I could at least see before.  still, I noticed the size of the partition "Macintosh HD" is not full hard disk size, I assume data in Windows disk is intact.

Here are my questions;

1. How to make Windows files visible from MacOS again? so that I can rescue important files at the worse scenario.
2. How to make it boot from this Windows partition?

Here are the requested outputs:

first one `sudo gpt -r show disk0`:

```
gpt show: disk0: Suspicious MBR at sector 0
     start        size  index  contents
         0           1         MBR
         1           1         Pri GPT header
         2          32         Pri GPT table
        34           6         
        40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
    409640  1174409400      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
1174819040     1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
1176088576   289058816      4  MBR part 12
1465147392        1743         
1465149135          32         Sec GPT table
1465149167           1         Sec GPT header
```

second one `sudo fdisk /dev/disk0`:

```
Disk: /dev/disk0    geometry: 91201/255/63 [1465149168 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: EE    0   0   2 - 1023 254  63 [         1 -     409639] <Unknown ID>
 2: AF 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [    409640 - 1174409400] HFS+        
 3: AB 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [1174819040 -    1269536] Darwin Boot 
 4: 0C 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [1176088576 -  289058816] Win95 FAT32L
```

the model of my Mac is MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012)

Comment: thank you klanomath, im commenting here because i am not sure if you get notified for editing.

Comment: I don't get notified but I see your question moving to the top. Please also add your Mac model. I think your 4th partition has the wrong partition type.

Comment: ok, I added my Mac model. How could I change the partition type back to correct one, please?

Comment: Now I reread the hyperlinked question thread in my post, and realized that the situation I have had was actually different. I modified partition from Mac, but in that post, he did it from Windows. So what I have done didn't make sense and I really would like to take back the change I made.

Comment: The problem is not solved. Because now I don't dare to make any changes on my own. Could anyone help me to make the partition type correct?